# creating nested JSON object in Java and passing it as request using RestPost method?

Tags: java, arrays, json, jsonobjectrequest

I want to build a JSON Object similar to the following structure in java, and then pass it as a request using the restPost method.

```
    {
      "fields": [
       {
          "SESSION_SESSIONNUMID": "500"
       },
       {
          "SESSION_STATUS": "BP"
       },
       {
          "SESSION_DESCRIPTION": "Updated"
       },
       {
          "SESSION_SESSIONDATE": "2016-07-20"
       },
       {
          "SESSION_CURRENCY_TYPE": "USD"
       }
     ]
   }
```

So this is what I did ,

```
    public void Insert() {
   try {
    String lstrPath = Constants.MIP_BASE_URI + "/api/te/JV/sessions";

   System.out.println("Path for creation of session :\n " + lstrPath);

  //create the JSON object containing the new contacts details.
    JSONObject array = new JSONObject();
    JSONObject object = new JSONObject();

    JSONObject A1 = new JSONObject();
    A1.put("SESSION_SESSIONNUMID " , "100 ");

   JSONObject A2 = new JSONObject();
   A2.put("SESSION_STATUS " , "BP");

   JSONObject A3 = new JSONObject();
   A3.put("SESSION_DESCRIPTION " , "CODING");

   JSONObject A4 = new JSONObject();
   A4.put("SESSION_SESSIONDATE" , "2016-10-20");

   JSONObject A5 = new JSONObject();
   A5.put("SESSION_CURRENCY_TYPE" , "USD");
   object.put("def", array);

   System.out.println("Passing request :\n" + A1.toString(1));

   JSONObject ljsonResponse = RestCalls.RestPost(lstrPath,
   A1, Constants.REQUESTING_CLASS.MIP);

   if (ljsonResponse != null) {
   Constants.MIP_TOKEN = ljsonResponse.getString("token");
   }
   System.out.println("Token from response: " + Constants.MIP_TOKEN);
      Constants.MIP_AUTH_HEADER = new BasicHeader("Authorization-Token",
        Constants.MIP_TOKEN);

    } catch (JSONException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(ConnectToMip.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null,ex);
    }
  }
```

And now the issue is that In the above code I am able to create multiple JSON Objects required to create a session , but now I am unable to figure out how do I send(pass) multiple JSON objects in the response.

Note : In the last line of code below, I send 1 JSON Object(A1) as a response, similarly I need to send multiple JSON Objects that I created (A2, A3 , A4 , A5) in the response for a successful POST .

Comment: if fields is an array it should contain similar object, you array look bit odd, you can bind multiple object to a single a single object like you did for the fields.

Comment: @jos : did you mean that I create something like this .,,                  JSONObject ljsonPost = new JSONObject();
    ljsonPost.put("SESSION_SESSIONNUMID","515");
    ljsonPost.put("SESSION_STATUS","BP");
    ljsonPost.put("SESSION_DESCRIPTION","Updated");
    ljsonPost.put("SESSION_SESSIONDATE","2016-11-09");
    ljsonPost.put("SESSION_CURRENCY_TYPE","USD");

Comment: yes "fields": [
    {
      "SESSION_SESSIONNUMID": "500",
      "SESSION_STATUS": "BP",
      "SESSION_DESCRIPTION": "Updated",
      "SESSION_SESSIONDATE": "2016-07-20",
      "SESSION_CURRENCY_TYPE": "USD"
    }
  ]

Comment: @jos : 1. if you look at ,y previous comment I created Json object for my attributes how do I create a JSON array called "fields". 2. when I execute the code which I have written in previous comment it gives " status code : 400" bad request.

Comment: you use your previous code and  create a `JSONArray json = new JSONArray(); json.put(A1); json.put(A2); json.put(A3); json.put(A4); json.put(A5); `

Comment: @jos  : Ok and then how do I send all that in my response in , JSONObject ljsonResponse = RestCalls.RestPost(lstrPath,
        A1, Constants.REQUESTING_CLASS.MIP);  Like A1 sends only 1 object and it would not accept JsonArray so how do i send A1....A5 in the response

Comment: @jos : Got it, Thank You Jos

Comment: JSONArray solved your issue? if its someother please add as answer

Answer (score 0):

First I convert my complex json into java like this,

```
JSONArray json = new JSONArray();
JSONObject Final = new JSONObject();

JSONObject A1 = new JSONObject();
      A1.put("SESSION_SESSIONNUMID" , "212");

      JSONObject A2 = new JSONObject();
      A2.put("SESSION_STATUS" , "BP");

      JSONObject A3 = new JSONObject();
      A3.put("SESSION_DESCRIPTION" , "CODING");

      JSONObject A4 = new JSONObject();
      A4.put("SESSION_SESSIONDATE" , "2016-10-20");

      JSONObject A5 = new JSONObject();
      A5.put("SESSION_CURRENCY_TYPE" , "USD");

    json.put(A1);
    json.put(A2);
    json.put(A3);
    json.put(A4);
    json.put(A5);

      Final.put("fields",json);
```

and then I pass Final into my tostring.